# Queue is always empty, even when filled from another thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have the following code, (contrived example):

```
# !/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import Queue as Q
import time
from random import randint

class SomeClass:

    def takes_awhile(self, mq):
        qjson = {}
        time.sleep(5)
        qjson.update(
            {"randint": randint(1, 9)}
        )
        mq.put(qjson)

    def record(self, jq):
        while True:
            self.takes_awhile(jq)
            time.sleep(0.05)


sc = SomeClass
jq = Queue()
scp = threading.Thread(target=sc.record, args=(jq,))
scp.start()


def qprint():
    try:
        rv = jq.get_nowait()
    except Q.Empty:
        return "Empty"
    return rv


while True:
    print qprint()
```

What I *want* this to do is for `qprint()` to always return immediately when called, printing `Empty` if too little time elapsed for `takes_awhile` to have `put` anything into the queue, but after about 5 seconds or so, I should start seeing the return value of `takes_awhile` (json with a random number), being pulled out of the queue. Instead, no matter how long the loop runs, it's always printing `Empty`.

What am I overlooking here?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few minor errors.  You need to instantiate SomeClass with `sc = SomeClass()`.  You're missing the parentheses.  It would also be a good idea to put a small sleep in your while loop.  With this printing so fast, you can't see the non 'Empty' statements.  Here's your revised code...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import Queue as Q
import time
from random import randint

class SomeClass(object):
    def takes_awhile(self, mq):
        qjson = {}
        time.sleep(1)
        qjson.update(
            {"randint": randint(1, 9)}
        )
        mq.put(qjson)

    def record(self, jq):
        while True:
            self.takes_awhile(jq)
            time.sleep(0.05)

sc = SomeClass()
jq = Queue()
scp = threading.Thread(target=sc.record, args=(jq,))
scp.start()

def qprint():
    try:
        rv = jq.get_nowait()
    except Q.Empty:
        return "Empty"
    return rv

while True:
    print qprint()
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is currently invalid - I get an exception like

> TypeError: unbound method record() must be called with SomeClass
>   instance as first argument (got Queue instance instead)

When passing parameters to `sc.record` inside the `Thread` call, you aren't referencing an instance of the `SomeClass` but instead the class itself - and so the `self` parameter isn't passed correctly. To resolve this change `sc = SomeClass()` to instantiate the class, and then the `threading.Thread` call passes an object.

I added a `while` loop so it runs indefinitely and prints results. After these changes it seems to work perfectly well for me.

Output looks like this:

```
Empty 
Empty 
Empty 
Empty 
{'randint': 4} 
Empty 
Empty
```

Here's the code I ran:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import time
import Queue as Q
from random import randint

class SomeClass:

    def takes_awhile(self, mq):
        qjson = {}
        time.sleep(5)
        qjson.update(
            {"randint": randint(1, 9)}
        )
        mq.put(qjson)

    def record(self, jq):
        while True:
            self.takes_awhile(jq)
            time.sleep(0.05)    

sc = SomeClass()
jq = Queue()
scp = threading.Thread(target=sc.record, args=(jq,))
scp.start()    

def qprint():
    try:
        rv = jq.get_nowait()
    except Q.Empty:
        return "Empty"
    return rv

while True:
    time.sleep(1)    
    print qprint()
```